# Laravel belongsTo / hasMany

Tags: php, laravel

I`ve a problem and i need to fetch all images ( path ) of my gallery table which own a museum and the user who ownes the museum.
I get the path of the images but these are not associated to the user_id who owns the museum.

So for short description:

Each user owns a museum and a museum has a gallery with multiple images ( path for the image url )

May table structure

- museums

  - ID
  - title
  - user_id
- users

  - ID
  - email
  - password
- gallery

  - ID
  - museum_id
  - title
  - path

My Gallery Model:

```
<?php

class Gallery extends \Eloquent {

protected $fillable = [];

public function museums() {
    //return $this->belongsToMany('Museums', 'id');
    return $this->belongsTo('Gallery', 'museum_id');
}
}
```

My Museum Model

```
<?php

class Museum extends Eloquent {

protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'title', 'description'];

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}

public function gallery()
{
    //return $this->belongsToMany('Gallery', 'museum_id');
    return $this->belongsToMany('Gallery');
}

}
```

My User Model

```
public function museums()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Museum');
}
```

And My MuseumController

```
public function show($id)
{
    //
    //$museum = Museum::where('id', '=', $id)->first();
    //return View::make('museums.detail', compact('museum'));
    $museum = Museum::findOrFail($id);
    $gallery = Gallery::with('museums')->get();
    //$museum = Museum::with('gallery')->get();

    return View::make('museums.detail', compact('museum', 'gallery'));
}
```

In my View i have

```
@foreach ($gallery as $image)
<img src="{{ $image->path }}" />
@endforeach
```

Comment: What is exception message? Or whatever else you are getting?

Answer (score 6):

You may try this:

```
// In User model
public function museum()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Museum');
}

// In Museum model
public function owner()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}

// In Museum model
public function galleries()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Gallery');
}

// In Gallery model
public function museum()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Museum');
}
```

Then in the controller:

```
$museums = Museum::with('galleries', 'owner')->get();
return View::make('museums.detail', compact('museums'));
```

In your view:

```
@foreach ($museums as $museum)

    {{ $museum->title }}

    // To get the user id from here
    {{ $museum->owner->id }}

    // Loop all images in this museum
    @foreach($museum->galleries as $image)

        <img src="{{ $image->path }}" />

        // To get the user id from here
        {{ $image->museum->owner->id }}

    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Comment: With your solution i get the error

Trying to get property of non-object (View: /home/vagrant/code/museum/app/views/museums/detail.blade.php)

Comment: There's a typo in the "view" code. @foreach($museum->gelleries .... should be galleries.